# Recursion / stacks and queues in cuda

Tags: cuda

To traverse a tree data structure in whatever form one might represent, one needs to use either recursion or use iteration with stacks and queues.

How would one do this on the GPU using CUDA? As far as I know,  neither recursion nor stack structures likes stacks and queues are supported in CUDA.

In context my problem is that of range searching, where given a point I want to traverse an octree data structure to find all points within a radius of 'r' centered at that point.

Comment: Trees aren't really very "parallel" data structures...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3644809/does-cuda-support-recursion

Answer (score 1):

The most effecient serial algorithms / data structures do not necessarily make the most effecient parallel implementations.

That said, this is not a new question and [a little bit of googling](http://forums.nvidia.com/index.php?showtopic=95710) can turn up interesting results.