# How to force cubin file generation for a higher compute version

Tags: cuda, nvidia, nvcc

In the samples provided with CUDA 6.0, I'm running the following compile command with error output:

```
foo@foo:/usr/local/cuda-6.0/samples/0_Simple/cdpSimpleQuicksort$ nvcc --cubin -I../../common/inc cdpSimpleQuicksort.cu
nvcc warning : The 'compute_10' and 'sm_10' architectures are deprecated, and may be removed in a future release.
cdpSimpleQuicksort.cu(105): error: calling a __global__ function("cdp_simple_quicksort") from a __global__ function("cdp_simple_quicksort") is only allowed on the compute_35 architecture or above

cdpSimpleQuicksort.cu(114): error: calling a __global__ function("cdp_simple_quicksort") from a __global__ function("cdp_simple_quicksort") is only allowed on the compute_35 architecture or above

2 errors detected in the compilation of "/tmp/tmpxft_0000241a_00000000-6_cdpSimpleQuicksort.cpp1.ii".
```

I then altered the command to this, with a new failure:

```
foo@foo:/usr/local/cuda-6.0/samples/0_Simple/cdpSimpleQuicksort$ nvcc --cubin -I../../common/inc -gencode arch=compute_35,code=sm_35 cdpSimpleQuicksort.cu
cdpSimpleQuicksort.cu(105): error: kernel launch from __device__ or __global__ functions requires separate compilation mode

cdpSimpleQuicksort.cu(114): error: kernel launch from __device__ or __global__ functions requires separate compilation mode

2 errors detected in the compilation of "/tmp/tmpxft_000024f3_00000000-6_cdpSimpleQuicksort.cpp1.ii".
```

Does this have anything to do with the fact that the machine I'm on is only Compute 2.1 capable and the build tools are blocking me?  What's the resolution... I'm not finding anything in the documentation that is clearly handling this error.

I looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18904319/cuda-global-function-recursion) question, and that... a link to documentation is simply not helping.  I need to know how I have to modify the compile command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the makefile that comes with that `cdpSimpleQuicksort` project. It shows some additional switches that are needed to compile it, due to CUDA dynamic parallelism (which is essentially the second set of errors you are seeing.) Go back and study that makefile, and see if you can figure out how to combine some of the compile commands there with `--cubin`.

The readers digest version is that this should compile without error:

```
nvcc --cubin -rdc=true -I../../common/inc -arch=sm_35 cdpSimpleQuicksort.cu
```

Having said all that, you should be able to compile for whatever kind of target you want, but you won't be able to run a cdp code on a cc2.1 architecture.

[cdp documentation](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#cuda-dynamic-parallelism)
and [here](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#parameter-buffer-layout)

Comment: The only other flags in that command are for specifying the host compiler (don't need... I'm after `cubin`), a 64b flag `-m64` object file declaration (not needed... I'm after `cubin` and then an `-lcudadevrt` flag, which doesn't do anything for me.  Adding `--cubin` to the makefile command complains about multiple compute instances.

Comment: ah... there's a `-dc` flag

Comment: -dc flag blows up for me.  Asks for key/value.  I tried `dc=true` and got `nvcc fatal   : Keywork '-dc' is not defined for option 'generate-code'`

Comment: Tried rdc:  `nvcc --cubin -I../../common/inc -gencode -rdc=true arch=code=sm_35 -lcudadevrt cdpSimpleQuicksort.cu` and got `nvcc fatal   : Keywork '-rdc' is not defined for option 'generate-code'`

Comment: That's all dorked up. You don't stick the `-rdc=true` in between the `-gencode` switch and the parameters for the `-gencode` switch.   And `arch=code=sm_35` isn't right. Try the command I list in my answer, or this: `nvcc --cubin -I../../common/inc -rdc=true -gencode arch=compute_35,code=sm_35 -lcudadevrt cdpSimpleQuicksort.cu`

Comment: Too wrapped up in trying to make what I was doing work to just think 'try copy/paste.'  Thank you!